# Приватные и не только переменные

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Есть задача подключить вебсокеты.

Выбором стал *JavaScript* и работающий модуль [socket.io](https://socket.io). Еще для работы с *Javascript* были установлены *babel*, *flow* и *webpack*.

### Проблема

Когда я пишу классы:

```
class Rcon {

  constructor(host: string, port: number, pass: string, timeout: number) { 
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    // code
  }

  // extra logic

}
```

то *Flow* линтер выдаёт:

[image: Property not found in Rcon]

## Вопросы

- Как мне прикажете работать с переменными в классах ES6 ?
- Как эти переменные и некоторые методы обозначить **private** / **protected** ?
- Что мне следует пересмотреть в своём подходе к кодингу на JS ?

Comment: У вас синтаксически правильный ES6 класс. 1) Линтер в зависимости от стиля кода или личных предпочтений можно отключить или настроить. 2) В ES6 нет понятия private/protected, можно конечно обозначать как `_privateProp` и `#protectedProp`, но это вкусовщина.  3) Из вопроса непонятно, для начала можете именовать классы более осмысленно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что во Flow перед использованием свойств их нужно объявить.

Например так:

```
class Rcon {
  host: string;
  port: number;

  constructor(host: string, port: number, pass: string, timeout: number) { 
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
  }
}
```

Этот факт даже отмечен в [официальной документации](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/classes/#toc-class-fields-properties):

> Whenever you want to use a class field in Flow you must first give it an annotation.